# I am not getting the count of results I want, when i scrape a webpage with BeautifulSoup&Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

When i try to get count of results, i got {{memberVm.disclosures.length}}. I want to get counts of result. It's at the top of the list. For example '34 bildirim bulundu.' I want to get 34, not {{memberVm.disclosures.length}}.

Page:

https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/bildirim-sorgu?srcbar=Y&cmp=Y&cat=4&s=srp2205201503&st=Yeni%20%C4%B0%C5%9F%20%C4%B0li%C5%9Fkisi&kw=yeni%20i%C5%9F%20ili%C5%9Fkisi&slf=ALL

My Codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/bildirim-sorgu?srcbar=Y&cmp=Y&cat=4&s=srp2205201503&st=Yeni%20%C4%B0%C5%9F%20%C4%B0li%C5%9Fkisi&kw=yeni%20i%C5%9F%20ili%C5%9Fkisi&slf=ALL'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

numberOfNotifications = content.find(style="font-weight : bold; ").get_text()
print(numberOfNotifications)
```

the result i got:
{{memberVm.disclosures.length}}

Comment: I believe it's because you're using `requests` to fetch the page text.  But `requests` cannot process javascript, which that page depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via javascript, so [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) doesn't see it. You can however simulate this request:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = 'https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/api/memberDisclosureQuery'

payload = {
    "bdkMemberOidList": [],
    "bdkReview": "",
    "discIndex": [],
    "disclosureClass": "",
    "fromDate": "",
    "fromSrc": "Y",
    "inactiveMkkMemberOidList": [],
    "index": "",
    "isLate": "",
    "mainSector": "",
    "market": "",
    "memberType": None,
    "mkkMemberOidList": [],
    "prd": "",
    "ruleType": "",
    "sector": "",
    "srcCategory": "4",
    "subjectList": [
        "srp2205201503"  # <-- from the URL "s=" parameter: "https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/bildirim-sorgu?srcbar=Y&cmp=Y&cat=4&s=srp2205201503&st=Yeni%20%C4%B0%C5%9F%20%C4%B0li%C5%9Fkisi&kw=yeni%20i%C5%9F%20ili%C5%9Fkisi&slf=ALL"
    ],
    "subSector": "",
    "term": "",
    "toDate": "",
    "year": ""
}


data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       publishDate                                                                               kapTitle  isOldKap disclosureClass disclosureType disclosureCategory                                                                            summary           subject ruleTypeTerm  disclosureIndex  isLate stockCodes  hasMultiLanguageSupport  attachmentCount
0        Dün 17:44                BİRLEŞİM MÜHENDİSLİK ISITMA SOĞUTMA HAVALANDIRMA SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                               Yeni İş İlişkisi Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1172706   False      BRLSM                    False                0
1        Dün 10:30                                              ASELSAN ELEKTRONİK SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                               Sözleşme İmzalanması  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1172603   False      ASELS                     True                0
2        Dün 09:16                                                           BEYAZ FİLO OTO KİRALAMA A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                         DS marka otomobil yetkili satıcılık faaliyetine başlanması  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1172562   False      BEYAZ                    False                0
3   14.07.23 18:14                                        GİRİŞİM ELEKTRİK SANAYİ TAAHHÜT VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                       Yeni Siparişler Alınması Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1172315   False      GESAN                     True                0
4   14.07.23 10:27                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1171962   False      ASTOR                    False                0
5   13.07.23 18:51                                                 ADEL KALEMCİLİK TİCARET VE SANAYİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                            Yeni İş İlişkisi Hakkında Bilgilendirme  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1171685   False       ADEL                    False                0
6   13.07.23 18:43                                           CW ENERJİ MÜHENDİSLİK TİCARET VE SANAYİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                               Yeni İş İlişkisi Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1171680   False      CWENE                    False                0
7   13.07.23 14:01                                              ASELSAN ELEKTRONİK SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                               Sözleşme İmzalanması  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1171374   False      ASELS                     True                0
8   12.07.23 18:00                                           CVK MADEN İŞLETMELERİ SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1171038   False      CVKMD                    False                0
9   12.07.23 13:39                                        GİRİŞİM ELEKTRİK SANAYİ TAAHHÜT VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                  Yeni İş Anlaşması  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1170830   False      GESAN                    False                0
10  11.07.23 17:20                  HİDROPAR HAREKET KONTROL TEKNOLOJİLERİ MERKEZİ SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                               Yeni İş İlişkisi Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1170457   False       HKTM                    False                0
11  11.07.23 14:47                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1170397   False      ASTOR                    False                0
12  11.07.23 14:46                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1170396   False      ASTOR                    False                0
13  10.07.23 18:11                                     ONCOSEM ONKOLOJİK SİSTEMLER SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                          Denizli Pamukkale Üniversitesi ile imzalanan sözleşme hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1169427   False      ONCSM                    False                0
14  10.07.23 11:30                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1168462   False      ASTOR                    False                0
15  10.07.23 11:07                                        GİRİŞİM ELEKTRİK SANAYİ TAAHHÜT VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                 Yeni İş Sözleşmesi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1168455   False      GESAN                    False                0
16  07.07.23 17:41                                 QUA GRANITE HAYAL YAPI VE ÜRÜNLERİ SANAYİ TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1167427   False      QUAGR                    False                0
17  07.07.23 13:47                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1167195   False      ASTOR                    False                0
18  07.07.23 13:47                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1167194   False      ASTOR                    False                0
19  07.07.23 11:38                            SAY YENİLENEBİLİR ENERJİ EKİPMANLARI SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                           GE (General Electic) Şirketiyle Sözleşme İmzalanması Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1166961   False      SAYAS                    False                0
20  06.07.23 16:44                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1166356   False      ASTOR                    False                0
21  06.07.23 16:43                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1166355   False      ASTOR                    False                0
22  06.07.23 09:08                                      GÜR-SEL TURİZM TAŞIMACILIK VE SERVİS TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                 Yeni İş Sözleşmesi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1166112   False      GRSEL                    False                0
23  05.07.23 16:54                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1165923   False      ASTOR                    False                0
24  04.07.23 17:26                                                                      ASTOR ENERJİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1165386   False      ASTOR                    False                0
25  04.07.23 08:58                                                  YEO TEKNOLOJİ ENERJİ VE ENDÜSTRİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                           Şirketin Yeni İş Alımı ve Sözleşme İmzalanması Hakkında.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1164986   False      YEOTK                    False                0
26  03.07.23 18:47                                                      ORGE ENERJİ ELEKTRİK TAAHHÜT A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA  Kalibre Boru Çatı Güneş Enerji Santralleri Projesine ilişkin sözleşme imzalanması  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1164638   False       ORGE                    False                0
27  03.07.23 09:23                                                  AZTEK TEKNOLOJİ ÜRÜNLERİ TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA     InfinityLab markasının Türkiye yetkili distribütörlüğünün kazanılması hakkında  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1163177   False      AZTEK                    False                0
28  23.06.23 17:36  SMART GÜNEŞ ENERJİSİ TEKNOLOJİLERİ ARAŞTIRMA GELİŞTİRME ÜRETİM SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni iş ilişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1161927   False      SMRTG                     True                0
29  22.06.23 18:31                                                    ARD GRUP BİLİŞİM TEKNOLOJİLERİ A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                             Tesk A.Ş. İle Sözleşme İmzalanması Hk.  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1161391   False      ARDYZ                    False                0
30  21.06.23 18:22                                                  AZTEK TEKNOLOJİ ÜRÜNLERİ TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                      Migros Ticaret A.Ş. ile imzalanan Tedarik Sözleşmesi Hakkında  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1161014   False      AZTEK                    False                0
31  21.06.23 16:19                                           CVK MADEN İŞLETMELERİ SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1160871   False      CVKMD                    False                0
32  20.06.23 18:15                                               ALFA SOLAR ENERJİ SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                   Yeni İş İlişkisi  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1160562   False      ALFAS                     True                0
33  19.06.23 20:46                                                    KOCAER ÇELİK SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.     False             ODA            ODA                ODA                                                                 Yeni İş Bağlantısı  Yeni İş İlişkisi            -          1160172   False      KCAER                     True                0
```

Comment: So far everything has worked fine. I want to go one step further.
When I click on an item from the list, the child window opens. There, at the bottom, there's a section called 'Açıklamalar'. I would like to get that text. I couldn't do it with above method. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @KaanAkdik Feel free to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you put what have you tried so far. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow to me answer my question here. So I opened new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916542/getting-text-from-a-webpage-using-web-scraping-with-pythonbeautifulsoup

Comment: I can't use the fromDate, toDate and index parameters here. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Actually i wonder how can i use that parameters, they do not provide user manual for this API.