# Getting text from a webpage using web scraping with Python&BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The website in the link lists news about companies traded on the Turkish stock exchange. Clicking on an item in the list opens a subwindow. In that window, there is a section called 'Aciklamalar' in the lower section as you can see on the photo. Is there any way to get this text using web scraping with Python, Json, BeautifulSoup?

Link:
https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/

[image: Photo]

I tried to learn a way in order to get text from a webpage using web scraping. I expect find a way to do it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not very familiar with web scraping. That's why I asked here without much attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data is loaded from external URL via Javascript, but you can simulate these requests using the [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) module.

It also appears not all links have this *Aciklamalar* section.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

popup_url = "https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/BildirimPopup/{}"
api_url = "https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/api/disclosures"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

for c in data:
    print(c["basic"]["companyName"], c["basic"]["disclosureIndex"])
    print()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(popup_url.format(c["basic"]["disclosureIndex"])).content,
        "html.parser",
    )
    td = soup.select_one("td:-soup-contains(Açıklamalar):not(:has(td))")
    if td:
        tr = td.find_next("tr")
        print(
            tr.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            .replace("oda_ExplanationTextBlock|", "")
            .strip()
        )
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186245

Şirketimiz, iştiraki OSWE Real Estate GMBH (Oswe) ile Konsolide hazırlanan 30.06.2023 Tarihli Gelir Tablosu' na göre ilgili dönemdeki faaliyetlerinden 168.528.259 TL brüt kar elde etmiştir. 31.12.2022 tarihli mali tablolarımızda; iştiraklerimizden Güney İstanbul ve Boğaziçi Çelik A.Ş portföyünde yer alan gayrimenkullerin 2022 yıl sonu değer artışlarından kaynaklanan gelir için %20 Kurumlar Vergisi karşılığı ayrılmıştır. 2023 yılı için Kurumlar vergisi oranı %25 olarak güncellendiğinden, aradaki %5 lik fark için bu dönemde 140.220.024 TL ilave vergi karşılığı ayrılması zorunluluğu doğmuştur. Ertelenmiş vergi giderleri kalemi altında sınıflanan bu giderin etkisiyle, Dönem Zararı (Ana Ortaklık Payı) 33.543.311 TL olarak gerçekleşmiştir. Aynı dönem için Solo hazırlanan Gelir Tablosu' nda; yer alan toplam 987.271.181 TL tutarındaki finansman giderinin 878.000.000 TL lik kısmı şirketimizin iştiraki OSWE' den almış olduğu borçtan kalan yaklaşık 106.000.000 EUR tutarındaki borç için hesaplanan kur farkından kaynaklanmaktadır. Bu kur farkı giderinin etkisiyle 906.111.514 TL "Dönem Net Zararı" gerçekleşmiştir. Yatırımcılarımızın bilgi ve dikkatine sunarız. Saygılarımızla…
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186244

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186243

Şirketimizin 01.01.2023 - 30.06.2023 Dönemi Faaliyet Raporu ekte PDF formatında sunulmuştur. Saygılarımızla...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186242

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186241

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMLAK KONUT GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş. 1186240

Şirketimiz projelerinden İstanbul    Şile    Çavuş    Arsa    Satışı    Karşılığı    Gelir    Paylaşımı    İşi (İdealist Cadde) kapsamında, 91 Ada 205 Parsel A, B ve C Bloklar ve Bu Bloklara Ait Altyapı ve Çevre Düzenleme İşlerinin kısmi kesin kabulü yapılmış olup Kısmi Kesin Kabul Tutanağı 15.08.2023 tarihinde onaylanmıştır. The Partial Final Acceptance for A, B ve C Block on 91 block 205 parcel and Related Infrastructure and Landscaping Works within the scope of our İstanbul    Şile    Çavuş Revenue Sharing Model Project in Return for Land Sale (Idealist Cadde) project has been made and the relevant Partial Final Acceptance Certificate has been approved on 15.08.2023. In accordance with the Turkish capital markets regulations, in case of any discrepency between the Turkish and English versions of disclosures, the Turkish language version which is published on the Public Disclosure Platform (Kamuyu Aydınlatma Platformu) shall prevail.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```